# Roman adage: The best death

Tags: resource-request, passage-request, passage-identification

There is a very famous quotation from one of the Roman authors to the effect that the best death is the one for which you can choose the time, and the second best is the one that comes unexpected. For some reason I am not able to find the source. Surely one of our expert Latinists can help me out.

Comment: That first part sounds very Senecan to me, in case that helps anyone in their search.

Comment: Here's half an answer (from Montaigne): For this reason it was that Caesar,
being asked what death he thought to be the most desired, made answer,
"The least premeditated and the shortest."—[Tacitus, Annals, xvi. 15]—

Comment: Montaigne (or the editors) have got the Tacitus ref. wrong.

Comment: Is it a commentary on Socrates?